# Creating separate databases for multiple themes in drupal 7.15

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-themes

How to create multiple databases for the multiple themes installed in sites/all/themes/.

Comment: Why do you want to create multiple databases?  Normally, there is no reason to do this in Drupal.

Comment: Furthermore, it is not necessary to have multiple databases for multiple themes. Multiple databases are used for a different purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you should start by reading the copious comments in the settings.php file for multiple databases, db table prefixing & even target db fallback. The db stanzas start on line 53, so it's not like it's even buried.  ;-)

(It's worth noting however that Drupal's db prefixing isn't designed to scale as you add more prefixes!)

Having said that, I would suggest carefully considering your reasons for wanting to use multiple databases. As Patrick points out, that's not necessary in Drupal for multiple themes, and you are adding a layer of complexity that you should make sure you really need-- for most cases this seems like it would be an anti-pattern.